# Store procedure execute query to SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have some trouble to execute a query from a **local stored procedure (SQL Server) to a SQL Azure**.
I wish to do some Insert queries **to my SQL Azure from a local scheduled stored procedure**.
I tried this:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
    @server='myServerName',
    @srvproduct='',
    @provider='sqlncli',
    @datasrc='myServerName.DATABASE.WINDOWS.NET',
    @location='',
    @provstr='',
    @catalog='dbName'

    EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname='myServerName',
    @useself='false',
    @rmtuser='user@myServerName.database.windows.net',
    @rmtpassword='pass'

    EXEC sp_serveroption 'myServerName', 'Collation Compatible', true;

    --my query
    insert into [k5wchg7vzf@windows.net]....
```

Comment: What is the trouble?  did you get an error?